# Borrar usuario por ID

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Tengo el siguiente enlace

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <a href="borrarUsuario/${session.userData.id}">Borrar Usuario</a>
</div>
```

Este es el método del controlador que borra

```
@RequestMapping(value="/borrarUsuario/{id}",method = RequestMethod.POST)  
     public String borrarUsuario(@RequestParam("id") Long id){  
         repoUsuario.delete(id); 
         return "views/_t/main";
}
```

La clase `UsuarioRepository` extiende de `JpaRepository`

Lo que no consigo es borrar el usuario por el `id`.

**SOLUCIÓN:**

El problema estaba en que no me cogía el valor de `id`, entonces busque que con esta manera si lo cogía sin necesidad de parsear la variable.

```
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <a th:href="@{'/borrarUsuario/' + ${session.userData.id}}">Borrar Usuario</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: ¿No será `RequestMethod.GET`?

Comment: Vale,acabo de probarlo y era eso,pero ahora me salta que el parámetro `id`no esta presente,osea no me coge el `id` del usuario

Answer (score 1):

Estás esperando un parámetro en la request (tienes la anotación `@RequestParam`), pero en realidad lo estás pasando como parte de la URL, por lo que deberías estar marcar el parámetro de tu método como un `@PathVariable`:

```
@PostMapping(value="/borrarUsuario/{id}")  
public String borrarUsuario(@PathVariable("id") Long id){  
     repoUsuario.delete(id); 
     return "views/_t/main";
}
```

Comment: Ahora me da el siguente error:`Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${session.userData"`

Comment: Mira tu HTML: no se está sustituyendo `${session.userData.id}` por su valor

Comment: @PabloLozano ¿ No habría que crear el objeto usuario y pasarlo al delete ?

Comment: @EduBw Probablemente, a menos que tenga un "deleteById"

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que pensar que lo que te llega por la url en el Pathvariable es una String, y tu necesitas el valor en Long para pasarselo a tu query de JPA por lo tanto debes recogerlo como una String y pasarlo parseado a Long. Intenta esto y debería funcionar:

```
@PostMapping(value="/borrarUsuario/{id}")  
public String borrarUsuario(@PathVariable("id") String id){  
     repoUsuario.delete(Long.parseLong(id)); 
     return "views/_t/main";

}
```

Comment: La transformación la hace automáticamente Spring, precisamente el error es que no se puede transformar lo que le está llegando